# IE 9 flickers in Standards mode but not in Quirk mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-9, standards

I am trying to render a big HTML table (800 rows and 170 columns) in IE 9. The problem is that it flickers constantly before rendering the page (I can see the html appearing and disappearing and the vertical scrollbar changing height) when IE 9 is in Standards mode, but no such flickering happens when IE 9 is in Quirks mode. this is a legacy application where my html page is a child of the main parent page. The main page was in Quirks mode in older versions but they have changed to Standards mode. I am not able to force the IE 9 browser to go to Quirks mode while loading my child page.

One more thing is that my child page is in a . I tried to remove the frame and use  but it still flickers. How can remove the flickering or force the IE 9 to go to Quirks mode programmatically? I tried to use older DOCTPYE or meta tag for Quirks mode in my child JSP but that did not work.

My html table is of fixed width and the columns are also of fixed width.

Comment: Since IE9 only one doctype is allowed in a document. A quickfix to rendering problems might be setting `offscreenBuffering=true`. You could also consider to load/show only a part of a large table.

Comment: this is not the case where the page appears without the stylesheet for sometime. in this case, the whole table appears with stylesheet and then disappears again

Comment: Do you realize the browser tries to render 136000 cells?

Comment: yes, but I cant do anything. Pagination is not an option. it was working in earlier versions of the product when they were using Quirks mode.